# Trouble passing down this.props.navigation to child components

Tags: react-native

I am having a little trouble accessing this.props.navigation.navigate in child pages within ViewPager. I have a page where there's a button called "Details" and upon clicking the button it should open up a new separate view (like a new Intent Activity).

Structure is:
Login page -> tap on "login" button -> opens MainPage having a custom CustomBottomNavigationBar with ViewPager component which takes {Object} of 5 different pages and renders them like:

In the root App.js I've already defined this configuration:

```
// App.js

import MainPage from './views/mainpage';
import PageOne from './views/pageoneview';
import PageTwo from './views/pagetwoview';
import PageOneDetailView from './views/PageOneDetailView';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: MainPage},
  PageOne: {screen: PageOne},
  PageTwo: {screen: PageTwo},
  PageOneDetailView: {screen: PageOneDetailView}
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
 });
```

```
// mainpage.js


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ToastAndroid
} from 'react-native';
import PageOne from './homepages/pageoneview';
import PageTwo from './homepages/pagetwoview';
import CustomBottomNavigationBar from './../components/CustomBottomNavigationBar';

export default MainPage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

screens = () => {
  return {
    p1: {page: <PageOne/>},
    p2: {page: <PageTwo/>}
  }
}

render() {
        return (
            <CustomBottomNavigationBar
                screensets={this.screens()}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Now in PageOne.js there is a button called "Details" and on tapping, it must open a new PageOneDetail.js

```
// pageoneview.js


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ToastAndroid
} from 'react-native';
import PageOneDetail from './homepages/PageOneDetailView';

export default PageOne extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

OpenView = (navigateObject, whichScreen) => {
        navigateObject(whichScreen);
}

render() {
  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.OpenView(navigate, 'PageOneDetailView')}>
                <Text> Details </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The error I get when I land on the MainPage is: `undefined is not an object this.props.navigation.navigate` when mainpage.js tries to load pageoneview.js

Please help me understanding how to fix this issue which I have been facing whole day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `navigation` prop is only accessible to screens, not children of those screens. You can pass down the navigation from the parent or use `withNavigation` HOC or `useNavigation` hook from `react-navigation-hooks` to access it everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your help, apparently the withNavigation HOC worked for me